# Choose one or Merger Multiple row with one different value column SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

please help me, how can I get one of duplicated data :
the table is like :

sampletable :

```
  datetime          |service|error_code |trx   |request
2015-06-22 23:05:11 |808    |00000000   |320456|160228
2015-06-22 23:05:11 |808    |00008008   |0     |2
2015-06-23 23:05:08 |808    |00000000   |324426|162213
2015-06-23 23:05:08 |808    |00008001   |0     |2
2015-06-23 23:05:08 |808    |00008008   |0     |2
2015-06-24 23:05:09 |808    |00000000   |333402|166701
2015-06-24 23:05:09 |808    |00008008   |0     |2
```

this is my query

```
  SELECT DATE(datetime) as datex, SUBSTR(datetime,12,8) as timex,
 service,error_code, MAX(trx) as trx, MAX(request) as req
    FROM (SELECT * FROM tmenu_trx WHERE error_code not in ('00000000'))x
        GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4
```

and the result from my query is

```
date       | time    |service| error_code|trx|req
2015-06-22 |23:05:11 |  808  |00008008   |0  |2
2015-06-23 |23:05:08 |  808  |00008001   |0  |2
2015-06-23 |23:05:08 |  808  |00008008   |0  |2
2015-06-24 |23:05:09 |  808  |00008008   |0  |2
```

but i hope the data is like :

```
    date       | time    |service| error_code|trx|req
    2015-06-22 |23:05:11 |  808  |00008008   |0  |2
    2015-06-23 |23:05:08 |  808  |00008001   |0  |2
    2015-06-24 |23:05:09 |  808  |00008008   |0  |2
```

or :

```
    date       | time    |service| error_code|trx|req
    2015-06-22 |23:05:11 |  808  |00008008   |0  |2
    2015-06-23 |23:05:08 |  808  |00008008   |0  |2
    2015-06-24 |23:05:09 |  808  |00008008   |0  |2
```

or :

```
date       | time    |service| error_code       |trx |req
2015-06-22 |23:05:11 |  808  |00008008          |0   |2
2015-06-23 |23:05:08 |  808  |00008001:00008008 |0   |2
2015-06-24 |23:05:09 |  808  |00008008          |0   |2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

for First one

```
SELECT DATE(datetime) as datex, SUBSTR(datetime,12,8) as timex,
service,error_code, MAX(trx) as trx, MAX(request) as req
FROM table1 WHERE error_code not in ('00000000')
GROUP BY DATE(datetime)
```

for Second one

```
SELECT DATE(datetime) as datex, SUBSTR(datetime,12,8) as timex,
service,max(error_code), MAX(trx) as trx, MAX(request) as req
FROM table1 
GROUP BY DATE(datetime)
```

for third one

```
SELECT DATE(datetime) as datex, SUBSTR(datetime,12,8) as timex,
service,GROUP_CONCAT(error_code SEPARATOR ':'), MAX(trx) as trx,MAX(request) as req
FROM table1 WHERE error_code not in ('00000000')
GROUP BY DATE(datetime)
```

Comment: thanks,,,,umm its still complicated but you give me an idea